# End of script output before headers - Perl

Tags: header, perl

Por que assim:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";
```

Funciona!

E assim:

```
my $tpl = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'index.html');
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n" , $tpl->output
```

eu tenho o erro:

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request.
>
> Error message:  End of script output before headers

- Já verifiquei permissão
- Já inseri html simples

Estou tendo problema, na hora que tento importar um HTML e preciso muito fazer isso. Alguém saberia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Linux? Apache? (espreita em `/var/log/apache2/error.log` para veres mais detalhes acerca do erro.)